# Have a one column text file, how to split it to several columns by a python script?

Tags: python

I have a text file in which has only one column. What I need is to split the only column to a few columns. For example, assume my file consists of :

10

20

30

40

50

e

1467

1608

1733

1767

1878

e

1787

1353

1024

693

423

I need it to become as below:

10 1467 1787

20 1608 1353

30 1733 1024

40 1767 693

50 1878 423

Just was wondering if you help me to do it with a Python script. In addition, if I can do it by writing some commands in OS X terminal, please let me know.

Comment: you want to turn split it into a colum every time "e" is reached?
can you post some of your code, "what have you tried?" also, is that the full list?

Comment: also - please explain how the items are split in this file? are they listed with spaces in between? new lines? commas?

Comment: I think this is a good example of the kind of question where "what have you tried" is an appropriate response. I don't envision SO as a website people can go to when they have a small task they want a program for for free.

Comment: please improve the formatting of your question. You may want to use the <.pre> <./pre> tags for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what it's possible to do with list comprehensions and the itertools module.

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile, izip, takewhile
>>> l = ['1', '2', 'X', '3', '4', 'X', '5', '6']
>>> splitter = 'X'
>>> fun = lambda e: e != 'X'
>>> begin = [e for e in takewhile(fun, l)]
>>> end = [e for e in dropwhile(fun, l)][1:]
>>> begin, end
(['1', '2'], ['3', '4', 'X', '5', '6'])
>>> # OUT: (['1', '2'], ['3', '4', 'X', '5', '6'])
>>> mid = [e for e in takewhile(fun, end)]
>>> end = [e for e in dropwhile(fun, end)][1:]
>>> begin, mid, end
(['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'])
>>> # OUT: (['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'])
>>> [e for e in izip(begin, mid, end)]
[('1', '3', '5'), ('2', '4', '6')]
>>> # OUT: [('1', '3', '5'), ('2', '4', '6')]
```

Of course, if the original list has a variable length, it is necessary to do this work in a loop.

I recommend you to test this kind of statements in a [BPython interpreter](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) so you can easily test interactive examples.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Modified to reflect changed data formats*

Based on your (new) sample data using 'e' as the group delimiter. The basic idea is to iterate over the lines in the file grouping as it goes and starting a new group whenever the delimiter is seen.

```
# testdata contains:
10
20
30
40
50
e
1467
1608
1733
1767
1878
e
1787
1353
1024
693
423
```

_

```
DELIMITER = 'e'
groups = []
this_group = []
for l in open('testdata', 'r'):
    l = l.strip()
    if l == DELIMITER and this_group:
        groups.append(this_group)
        this_group = []
    else:
        this_group.append(l)
if this_group:
    groups.append(this_group)

for t in zip(*groups):
    print ' '.join(t)

10 1467 1787
20 1608 1353
30 1733 1024
40 1767 693
50 1878 423
```

Comment: Apologize to all. I edited my previous post since items were presented in a row rather than in a column !!!. I was wondering if you take a look at my edited question and guide me based on that...Indeed, I'm sorry for my fault. I was not familiar how to post a column of items in my post since it was presented as a row of elements in my previous question :-).

There is no space between individual items in the consecutive rows meaning that there is no space between 10, 20, 30, etc...

Comment: Why Python does not have the ability to play with columns ?. For example, we cannot have a "for" loop that iterates over columns whereas we can simply iterate over lines by the following statement :

 for line in file_1.readlines():

Comment: @user1581399: Answer updated to reflect your revised data format.

Comment: @mhawke The file handle will leak in your example. It is better to use `with open('testdata') as f: for l in f: ...` as that will ensure `f` is closed even on exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @reece , but as you say it is just an example, not bullet proof code... I got a bit lazy. Let's "leave it as an exercise" for the reader.

Comment: Many thanks dear reece and mhawke :-). Your responses were of great help.

Cheers,
A

Comment: @user1581399: The customary way of thanks is also by upvoting and accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the content of an entire file into a list using:

```
def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().split()
```

Running `data = read_data('test.txt')` using a `text.txt` that contains:

```
10
20
30
e
11
21
31
e
12
22
32
```

Will result in:

```
data = ['10', '20', '30', 'e', '11', '21', '31', 'e', '12', '22', '32']
```

NOTE: `test.txt` can be formatted with spaces, tabs and newlines in any way as `split()` will handle them correctly!

The data should really be in a 2D array that does not contain the 'e' entries. This can be done using the following:

```
def list_to_grid(data):
    ret  = []
    line = []
    for entry in data:
        if entry == 'e':
            if len(line) != 0:
                ret.append(line)
                line = []
            else:
                line.append(int(entry))
    if len(line) != 0:
        ret.append(line)
    return ret
```

NOTE: I'm sure there's a more Pythonic way of doing this, but it works.

Running `data = list_to_grid(read_data('test.txt'))` on the `text.txt` file will result in:

```
data = [[10, 20, 30], [11, 21, 31], [12, 22, 32]]
```

What you are doing is transposing the 2D array. That is, given `data[i][j]`, it has the new position `data[j][i]`. Now this data can be transposed to get the desired sequence:

```
def transpose(data):
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        ret.append([data[j][i] for j in range(0, len(data[i]))])
    return ret
```

Which for `tdata = transpose(data)` gives:

```
 data = [[10, 20, 30], [11, 21, 31], [12, 22, 32]]
tdata = [[10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 32]]
```

Now print it out:

```
def print_data(data):
    for line in data:
        print ' '.join([str(x) for x in line])
```

Using `print_data(tdata)` results in:

```
10 11 12
20 21 22
30 31 32
```

Which is what you wanted.